# Can I write a thesis or paper without my school's support?

Tags: research-process, thesis, masters, university, paper-submission

I'm a Master's student, and I'd like to write a thesis, but my grade's don't qualify me (you need at least a 3.75/4.0 GPA). Can I just go ahead and write on? Is there anything I should be aware of?

I have a similar question regarding research papers. Can I just write and submit a paper to a conference?

Comment: For your second question, the questions tagged [tag:independent-researcher] may be helpful.

Comment: Have you asked whether it's possible to get an exception to the GPA requirement for writing a thesis?

Answer (score 9):

> Can I just write and submit a paper to a conference?

Yes, absolutely anyone can write and submit papers.  It's difficult to do a good job on your first attempt if you don't have any guidance from a mentor, but it's not impossible.

> I'm a Master's student, and I'd like to write a thesis, but my grade's don't qualify me (you need at least a 3.75/4.0 GPA). Can I just go ahead and write on?

Nobody can stop you from writing something, but it won't be a thesis.  You'll lack supervision from an advisor, which will make it much harder to do a good job, and even if you manage to do a good job the department will not accept it as a thesis.  (Bureaucracies don't work that way, plus working with an advisor is considered a crucial part of the process.)

Comment: And remember that most conferences (not to say all, at least in CS), requires the attendance of at least one of the authors, if the work is accepted. Beyond the inscription fee, that would imply, in general, in travel and hotel costs...